# How to sandbox my application in Xcode 4.2?

Tags: xcode4.2, sandbox

I'm using Xcode 4.2. I have created an iPhone application in which the user will be able to play video by selecting an input file. While running on simulator I've just specified the path of the input file.

While running the application on a device, I read that I need to sandbox my application, so that I can add files and select them while using my application.

Now I'm not able to figure out how I should sandbox my application. I can't find "Enable Sandbox" option anywhere.

Kindly help!

Comment: this has nothing to do with Xcode

Answer (score 0):

iOS are always sandboxed , that's why there is no checkbox

- you can only access files in your sandbox (which will only contain your app by default)
- you have to pick media using the UIImagePicker or the SLAsset library directly

---

#### if you want to 'see your sandbox in itunes'/ iTunes File Sharing

for itunes sharing follow e.g. http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app (good tutorial)

Comment: When I connected my iPhone device, I'm not able to see my application under File Sharing in iTunes. So I assumed it is not Sandboxed by default. Anywhere I need to set the permissions or enable it in Xcode?

Comment: it is sandboxed by default ;) really -- but sharing is distinct from that.. Ill look into the docs

Comment: But how do I add files to my Application Sandbox?

Comment: you ship in your bundle or like I said.. via ImagePicker or AssetLib. For sharing: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app (good tutorial)

Comment: the iOS sandbox is always there but since there is no filesystem on IOS it works a bit different than on OSX.